# Pivot table with two columns + max third column

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a table with columns A, B and C. Values on column A are a list of issues that may repeat, column B is the reason of this specific occurrence and column C is the date it occurred.

I need a pivot table that shows, for each distinct issue from column A, its latest date of occurrence and the reason of that latest occurrence.

**Example:**

`Issue Title | Reason Description | Occurrence
------------+--------------------+--------------
Issue 1     | Reason X           | Jan 1, 2020
Issue 2     | Reason Z           | Jan 15, 2020
Issue 1     | Reason W           | Feb 5, 2020
Issue 2     | Reason Y           | Feb 20, 2020
Issue 3     | Reason X           | Mar 3, 2020`

**Desired pivot table:**

`Issue Title | Reason Description | Last Occurrence
------------+--------------------+--------------
Issue 1     | Reason W           | Feb 5, 2020
Issue 2     | Reason Y           | Feb 20, 2020
Issue 3     | Reason X           | Mar 3, 2020`

The last occurrence for "Issue 1" was feb 5, reason W. Last occurrence for "Issue 2" was feb 20, reason Y, etc.

[Click here to see excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw2XF.png)

Any idea on how can I achieve this? I know I can create a pivot table with column A + max(column C), but I have no idea on how can I add column B without screwing it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not paste a PNG, as I cannot convert that to excel.  Just paste in the values.

Comment: I've just added my example as a code in addition to the PNG screenshot (same content).

Comment: It's doable, but not with pivot table. A macro might be able to do the trick. Here is how I would do it:
1. sort by issue (ASC) and by Occurence (DESC)
2. Delete duplicate rows based on issue and reason

Comment: Please add a rule and example data that defines what happens when Multiple "Issue 3 on Mar 3, 2020" are found, having different Reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any excel that macro that would work; maybe others can.  Instead I created a short SQL and procedure that will get what is wanted.

```
Option Explicit
'
' needs  Tools / References / Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects v.v Library
'

Sub doSortaPivot()

    ' make sure that sheets are present and properly named
    Dim RawSheet As String, ResultSheet As String, nRow As Long
    RawSheet = "rawData"
    ResultSheet = "Result"
    Sheets(RawSheet).Select
    Sheets(ResultSheet).Select

    ' clear out the Result
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    nRow = 0


    '---Connecting to the Data Source---
    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With

    '---Create the SQL for the Request---
    sql = "  " & _
      "  Select                                   " & _
      "      rd.[Issue Title]                     " & _
      "      ,rd.Occurrence                       " & _
      "      ,rr.[Reason Description] as Reason   " & _
      "  From (                                   " & _
      "      Select                               " & _
      "        [Issue Title]                      " & _
      "        ,max(Occurrence) as Occurrence     " & _
      "      From [Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=0;HDR=Yes;Database=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";Readonly=True].[rawData$]  " & _
      "      Group By [Issue Title]               " & _
      "       ) as rd                             " & _
      "  Left Join                                " & _
      "      [Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=0;HDR=Yes;Database=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";Readonly=True].[rawData$]  as rr  " & _
      "   On   rd.[Issue Title] = rr.[Issue Title]   " & _
      "   And  rd.[Occurrence]  = rr.[Occurrence]    " & _
      "         "

    '---Get the Data---
    Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)

    '---Put the data into the Result sheet
    Dim j As Long
    Do While Not rs.EOF

        Sheets(ResultSheet).Select
        nRow = nRow + 1
        If nRow = 1 Then    ' do the column headings
            For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                Cells(nRow, j + 1) = rs.Fields(j).Name
            Next j
            nRow = nRow + 1
        End If
        For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            Cells(nRow, j + 1) = rs.Fields(j).Value
        Next j

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop


    '---Clean up---
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```